# libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so cannot be found

Tags: c++, azure

i have a problem running an [Azure TTS tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/cpp/linux/text-to-speech).
I have stated my problem [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/1428) and there werent any response.

What i have done is follows:

```sh
# Installed requirements
apt-get update
apt-get -y install build-essential libssl1.0.0 libasound2 wget

# Compiled it using make
make

# with the compilation verbose, meaning it compiled with these parameters
g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld \
    --std=c++14 \
    -I ~/speechsdk/include/cxx_api -I ~/speechsdk/include/c_api \
    -L ~/speechsdk/lib/x64 \
    -lMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core -pthread -l:libasound.so.2

# Run
./helloworld
```

However i got the following error message

```
./helloworld: error while loading shared libraries: libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[Edits]
included spaces between `-L, -I` and `~/speechsdk/*`. Used `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`

Comment: @TedLyngmo `find ~/speechsdk -name '*.so' | grep -i Speech.core.so` gives `~/speechsdk/lib/x64/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so` among those from other directories such as `x64, centos7-x64, arm64, x86, arm32`

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, it is now like this :
`g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld 
    --std=c++14 
    -I ~/speechsdk/include/cxx_api -I ~/speechsdk/include/c_api 
    -L ~/speechsdk/lib/x64 
    -lMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core -pthread -l:libasound.so.2` 
For easier visibility, i updated this format in the question. Same error still shows.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread the question yesterday. You actually got the error in runtime. Try adding the directory to the linker by using the linker option `-rpath`  (`-Wl,-rpath,~/speechsdk/lib/x64`) or `-rpath-link` (`-Wl,-rpath-link,~/speechsdk/lib/x64`) when compiling.

Comment: @TedLyngmo meaning i just add them to the end like this ? `g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld --std=c++14 -I ... -L ...  -l... -Wl -rpath ~/speechsdk/lib/x64` ?

Comment: No, but `-Wl,-rpath ~/speechsdk/lib/x64` should work. The `,` should be there, but if you use `~` you can't have the `,` after `rpath`, so `-Wl,-rpath ~/speechsdk/lib/x64`. I just tested that syntax using another library and that worked for me.

Comment: Did you have any success?